# Android TableLayout just above center

Tags: android, xml

How would one go about making a TableLayout centered just above the center of the parent?

Currently I'm using `android:layout_gravity="center"` which is putting the layout exactly in the center. I've tried playing around with padding, but I couldn't find a solution.

I would like to have it above the center by about 10 dp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout_centerVertical="true"` instead of the gravity.

Then increase the size of your layout and use the `paddingBottom` to push your layout a bit on the top.

Comment: I used `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and then used padding above the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Take an invisible view in center of parent, and make your tableview align above that view with required margin at bottom like below. You can apply negitive margin also.

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/centerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#ff0000">
.....
</TableLayout>
```